# Is it possible to have AJAX loaded content with ZURB foundation tabs?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

Based on the docs (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ui.php#nice2), it seems like you have to have the full page content ready and going beforehand. Is it possible to load in via AJAX instead of pre-loading for these tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to load content via ajax. I was able to add tabs at run time using jQuery's appendTo() method and the newly added tabs & content worked fine.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22020108/1158234) is a solution that I used for Foundation 5

Answer (score 2):

I load the content in a div revealLayer and then I append to the revel modal div and work fine to me. The code is like this

HTML

```
<div id="revealLayer"></div>
<div id="revealModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
<a href="#" class="button" id="buttonForModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonForModal").click(function() {
        $( '#revealLayer' ).empty();
        $( '#revealLayer' ).load( 'url-to-load' );
        $( '#revealLayer' ).appendTo( '#revealModal' );
        $( '#revealModal' ).reveal();
        return false;
    });
});
```